# Is there a way to make a dft from an complex ma

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

the problem is to fourie transform ( cv::dft ) a signal with fourie descriptors. So the mat should be complex numbers :(

But my problem is how can make a mat with complex numbers ? Please help me to find an example or any other that show me how to store a complex number(RE + IM) to a mat ?

Is there a way to use merge ?

My code

```
Mat koopa(contours5[0], true);
Mat re;
Mat im;
re.convertTo(re,CV_32SC1);
im.convertTo(re, CV_32SC1);
vector channel(2);
// split coordinates in two mat
split(koopa, channel);
re = channel[0];
im = channel[1];
Mat planes[] = { re, im };
Mat complexImg;
merge(planes, 2, complexImg);
dft(complexImg, complexImg);
split(complexImg, planes);
```

why doesn't work ? Link [error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNKzr.png)

Comment: Please don't post a picture (or worse, a link to a picture) of your error(s). Copy-paste the *text* of the error  into the question. And please, copy the *complete* error/build log, and also please mark out on which lines you are getting the errors.

Comment: I think its quite clear. Its a datatype mismatch problem. You are not imputing the data type dft expects. If you check your error you can see that. Read what an assertion is in programing also.

Comment: Matlab gives me with the identical content of the matrix a totally different result why?                                                            Opencv
[4718, 4534;
-19.523417, 35.777447;
-299.86957, -1409.5095]

-10,5683297180044 + 0,00000000000000i
-2219,69900075834 + 721,815545935725i
13,4949824676201 + 34,0769293182730i
-2219,69900075834 - 721,815545935725i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it wants CV_32FC or CV_64FC datatype, but you feed CV_32SC.

Comment: okay I have fixed it , and the code runs ! But Matlab gives me with the identical content of the matrix a totally different result why?

Comment: Seems you need normalize result. See DFT_SCALE flag.

Comment: is there nothing to do except to change the dft funktion ? from dft(complexImg, complexImg); in dft(complexImg, complexImg, DFT_SCALE); ? when I do this the results are very small and there is no peak so high how in matlab ??

Comment: is it really like in the above example , the pay in the matrix complexImg now imaginary numbers in the form zi = 5 + 6i are generated by this merge ?

Comment: Can't really undestand the problem. But take a look also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045768/fft-and-ifft-difference-between-results-in-matlab-and-opencv/20046438#20046438

Comment: the problem is matlab results are high numbers ( 0 to 700 or 1500)  and the first result after the fft in matlab have only a real part ... in openCV after the dft the results are very low numbers ( 0 to 30 ) and the first result after the dft have real und complex part ...why is there such a difference ?

Comment: Try use DFT_SCALE|DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT flags together.

Comment: And it seems that MALAB's fft gives you magnitude and phase, but OpenCV gives imaginary and real parts of transform. These things are not the same.

Comment: there is no difference with these flags to the result of behind the other flags :( , i will check your answer with the magnitude and the phase but i think matlab gives RE and IM back after use fft ?